# What pattern to use with a Strategy Pattern to avoid duplicate code inside Concrete Strategies?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm relatively new to design patterns and in the following example I am using what I believe is a Strategy Pattern. However, I am repeating myself inside **some, not all,** concrete strategies and wondering is there a way to avoid this? Notice how ACommand and CCommand have the same code before doing something unique.

```
public interface Command 
{
    public boolean execute(CommandSender sender, String[] args);
    public String getName();
    //...
}

public abstract class PlayerCommand implements Command 
{
    protected BukkitPlugin plugin = BukkitPlugin.getInstance();

    private String name;
    //...

    public PlayerCommand(String name) 
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() 
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    //...
}
```

**ACommand**

```
    public class ACommand extends PlayerCommand
    {
        public ACommand()
        {
            super("A");
        }

        public boolean execute(CommandSender sender, String[] args)
        {
            Player player = (Player) sender;
            PlayerInventory inventory = player.getInventory();
            ItemStack itemInHand = inventory.getItemInHand();

            if(itemInHand.getType() != Material.COMPASS)
            {
                sender.sendMessage("You must be holding a phone to use this command");
                return true;
            }

            int id = itemInHand.getDurability();

            MobilePhoneManager phoneManager = plugin.getMobilePhoneManager();       
            boolean isMobilePhone = phoneManager.isMobilePhone(id);

            if(!isMobilePhone)
            {
                sender.sendMessage("You must be holding a mobile phone to use this command");
                return true;
            }

            //DO SOMETHING UNIQUE HERE
        }
}
```

**BCommand**

```
public class BCommand extends PlayerCommand
        {
            public BCommand()
            {
                super("B");
            }

            public boolean execute(CommandSender sender, String[] args)
            {
                //SOMETHING ELSE
            }
    }
```

**CCommand**

```
    public class CCommand extends PlayerCommand
    {
        public CCommand()
        {
            super("C");
        }

        public boolean execute(CommandSender sender, String[] args)
        {
            Player player = (Player) sender;
            PlayerInventory inventory = player.getInventory();
            ItemStack itemInHand = inventory.getItemInHand();

            if(itemInHand.getType() != Material.COMPASS)
            {
                sender.sendMessage("You must be holding a phone to use this command");
                return true;
            }

            int id = itemInHand.getDurability();

            MobilePhoneManager phoneManager = plugin.getMobilePhoneManager();       
            boolean isMobilePhone = phoneManager.isMobilePhone(id);

            if(!isMobilePhone)
            {
                sender.sendMessage("You must be holding a mobile phone to use this command");
                return true;
            }

            //DO SOMETHING UNIQUE HERE
        }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a command pattern. If you see the same line of code all the time factor it out into a function. no need for a new design pattern.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the [template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) as the basis for a common base class between `ACommand` and `CCommand`.  The template method in the base class would hold the common code, then call an (`abstract`) method to `doSomethingUnique()`.

Answer (score 0):

Andre is right on all counts. You are using a Command pattern and you just need to tweak your interface a bit to include some notion of whether the command is currently in a state where it can execute

```
bool canExecute();
boll canExecute(args)
```

You usually don't see the execute method return anything though.

HTH,
Berryl