# How to avoid duplicate code while using Strategy Design Pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I am new to design patterns and thinking about using Strategy design pattern for implementing code in my backend service. However, the Strategies are having duplicate code. I have the following classes:-

```
class StrategyA implements Strategy {
  private Helperclass1 helperclass1;
  private Helperclass2 helperclass2;
  private Daoclass dao;

  public void execute(Object obj) {
    updatedObj = helperclass1.method(obj);
    updatedObj = helperclass2.method2(updatedObj);
    updatedObj = updateObj(updatedObj);
    dao.update(updatedObj);
  }

  private Object updateObj(Object obj) {
    //update obj & return;
  }
}

class StrategyB implements Strategy {
  private Helperclass1 helperclass1;
  private Helperclass2 helperclass2;
  private Daoclass dao;

  public void execute(Object obj) {
    updatedObj = helperclass1.method(obj);
    updatedObj = helperclass2.method2(updatedObj);
    dao.update(updatedObj);
  }
}

class StrategyC implements Strategy {
  private Helperclass1 helperclass1;
  private Daoclass dao;

  public void execute(Object obj) {
    updatedObj = helperclass1.method(obj);
    dao.update(updatedObj);
  }
}
```

What should I do to remove duplicate code from Strategy pattern? I am considering not using the design pattern to avoid code duplication. Can anyone suggest a better design pattern for this usecase?
I read about some similar situations and found that Command or Template patterns may be considered as an alternative (link:[What pattern to use with a Strategy Pattern to avoid duplicate code inside Concrete Strategies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371746/what-pattern-to-use-with-a-strategy-pattern-to-avoid-duplicate-code-inside-concr)). However I am not sure how I can effectively use these patterns for my use-case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make one general strategy that executes multiple strategies. Like event handling. The idea:

```java
interface Strategy
{
    Object execute(Object obj);
}
class MultiStrategy implements Strategy
{
    private Strategy[] strategies;
    public Object execute(Object obj)
    {
        foreach (Strategy s : strategies)
            obj = s.execute(obj);
        return obj;
    }
}
class Strategy1 implements Strategy
{
    private Helperclass1 helperclass1;
    public Object execute(Object obj)
    {
        return helperclass1.method1(obj);
    }
}
class Strategy2 implements Strategy
{
    private Helperclass1 helperclass2;
    public Object execute(Object obj)
    {
        return helperclass2.method2(obj);
    }
}
```

And the usage would be kinda like:

```java
Strategy s = new MultiStrategy(new Strategy[]
{
    new Strategy1(helper1),
    new Strategy2(helper2),
});
```

In my example the strategies 1 and 2 and in fact adapters, but that's also a common use case. The benefit of this is that you can use the same code of `MultiStrategy` for any number of substeps, or even combine multiple multi strategies under the `Strategy` interface to make trees of strategies. Note though, that this `MultiStrategy` is another pattern in and of itself, just using a single-layer strategy is not enough to clean this up in your case. I don't remember they call it officially, but I guess you can call it event handling.

Comment: Thanks for this. This solution helped me reduce duplicate code

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate duplicate code through inheritance, if you can factor the common code out.